# Python Tkinter cant unbind Triple Click

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, binding

So I have some tags (strings the user made), they are on display in a text widget at all times. Basically if there are tags to display, you need to be able to triple click on them and it will lead to a editing menu. But if there aren't any tags to display, I don't want people to be able to triple click on it.

So my thought was bind triple click to the appropriate function if there are tags to display, and unbind it if there aren't any tags to display.

```
for tag in sorted(tags_pre_listed):#This loop will just check the tags and OK them for use.
    if tag[0:4]=='TAG-' and tag not in used_tags: # Just avoids duplicates.
        tags_display_box.insert(Tk.END, '#'+tag[4:]+' ') #inserts the tag to the display.
        used_tags.append(tag)
if len(used_tags)>0:                   #If any tags were used to display, it will bind Triple click.
    tags_display_box.bind("<Triple-1>", delete_tag)
else:                                  #This is where it tries to unbind if there are no tags, but fails.
    tags_display_box.unbind('<Button-1>',"<Triple-1>")
```

The issue I get is

```
TclError: can't delete Tcl command
```

Sorry It may be a rookie answer for all I know but I have done my research and can't find a way around it at all T-T

Thanks so much for reading and for any advice!

Comment: I think ``<Button-1>`` is the right event format for left button.Try by replacing ``<Button 1>`` with ``<Button-1>``

Comment: @a874 good spot, I fixed that and will update the code in my post, but sadly I still hit the same error... T-T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
tags_display_box.unbind('<Button 1>',"<Triple-1>")
```

should read:

```
tags_display_box.unbind('<Triple-1>')
```

As it is you're trying to unbind something that's not bound from a command that does not exist.

Comment: YOU BEAUTIFUL HUMAN! XD Thank you, it worked! If you would be willing would you elaborate a little more on that via comment? I don't quite understand why that worked, I just know it did lol.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not really that up on tcl/tk but as I understand it, tkinter is a thin (or thin-ish) wrapper around tcl/tk. In raw tcl/tk you define functions in tcl, then use "bind" to bind keys or mouse buttons to them. You can then either unbind the key, leaving the function defined; or, you can unbind the key *and* "un-define" the tcl function. With the extra argument, the interpreter is trying to find a function named `<Triple-1>` and delete it.